# android BluetoothChat use send receive methods from another class

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

Hello im using the BluetoothChat example in order to communicate with an arduino. Everything works so far and now i want to access the sendMessage() method in order to be able to send data not from the main class but from another that ive created. Here is the BluetoothChat send function in the BluetoothChat.java

```
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);
        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
    }
}
```

Now i want to access it from my Config.java . Here is what i have done so far. I changed the private void sendMessage to public and in the Config.java ive added these:

```
BluetoothChat firstClass = new BluetoothChat();
```

and in onCreate this

```
firstClass.sendMessage("test");
```

Although im not getting any errors when im switching to the Config.java activity the app crashes..
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanx!

logcat

> 10-08 22:49:15.125: D/dalvikvm(1541): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 98K, 47% free 2962K/5511K, external 3943K/4883K, paused 23ms
>   10-08 22:49:15.128: D/BluetoothSocket(1541): socket already in closing state:android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@40535c88
>   10-08 22:49:15.128: D/BluetoothSocket(1541): socket already in closing state:android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@40523b10
>   10-08 22:49:15.296: E/BluetoothChat(1541): -- ON STOP --
>   10-08 22:49:20.585: D/AndroidRuntime(1541): Shutting down VM
>   10-08 22:49:20.585: W/dalvikvm(1541): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat.sendMessage(BluetoothChat.java:218)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.Config.onItemSelected(Config.java:45)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:871)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:42)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:837)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>   10-08 22:49:20.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1541):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

BluetoothChat class is an activity. Activity objects are managed by Android OS (created, onCreate, onResume and other methods are called).

So, you shoudn't do something like this:

```
BluetoothChat firstClass = new BluetoothChat();
```

There are couple of ways how you can reuse this functionality

a) Copy from BluetoothChat and paste it to Config (let's for one second forget about code duplication).

You will need to copy the code from onCreate, onStart and other methods which manages mBluetoothAdaptor method

b) If you are going to keep both BluetoothChat activity and Config activity, you can move reusable code to some helper class (which isn't activity) and use it from both activities.

P.S. I would recommend to read up a little bit about activities, their lifecycle, because without this knowledge it will be very hard to develop any android app.

Comment: Thanx for your answer but with that way, i have to connect each time im moving from one acticity to the other

Comment: In order to do what you describe in b) , do i have to create e new class that extends Appilication in order to pass the data from one class to the other? And if so can you please give me an example because whatever ive tryed my app crashes..

Comment: Actually, all you need to do is to create a sigleton (BTW. Documentation - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html recommends this way). Sigleton will own BluetoothAdapter and each activity will get an this singleton and use it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Something like this i was describing in my previous comment! Im trying to find more info on how to do this but my lack of experience in the android development doesn't help me.. =\ Can you give me more specific info on this perhaps with an example of how to create an Application (or Singleton) class and use it in all of my classes?

Comment: 2lucky13: I understand that you are eager to get something working (which is good). However, the way you handle it isn't optimal. Even if somebody help you with one of the problem ("how to create singleton class"), you will stuck on another one within a day (based on your question I have a feeling that you lack the good fundamentals on Java and Android). My recommendation would be - get a book on Java and get a book on Android. You will be able to read them through within couple of days and it will speed up everything tenfold.

Answer (score 1):

You need Thread's or AsyncTask for send ant message from Android via Bluetooth.
See this simple example: http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino5.php